# ios8 "removeFromSuperview" crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

```
NSArray *viewsToRemove = [scrollView subviews];
for (UIView *v in viewsToRemove) {
    [v removeFromSuperview];
}
```

When update device to ios8 the code will crash [removeFromSuperview], and show message "Thread 1:EXC_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x5000000c")

Any another code can instead it?

Comment: Try with `[[scrollView subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(removeFromSuperview)];`

Comment: Your removing the the Scroll Indicators I'd reckon.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *viewsToRemove = [scrollView subviews];
for (UIView *v in viewsToRemove) {
   if ([v isKindOfClass:[UIView Class]]) {       
      [v removeFromSuperview];
   }
}
```